# Tridion GUI strange behaviour on selecting items for Component link, it freezes

Tags: 2011

I am facing a strange issue on SDL Tridion 2011 GUI. Where on one specific system and in a specific Publication; when we select a Component link the overlay opened freezes with no Folder/Components visible. When the same thing is tried on some other Publication, it is working fine.

We are using around 5 systems which are having access to Tridion and the above issue we are facing only on one system, on others it is fine. I tried clearing cache/restarting; still the same.

There is a strange error whenever I try to add the Component on the Page, GUI is showing error about a Component ID not existing and then hanging the whole browser. I tried clearing the Tridion cache from config still the error is coming.

Please help me how I can resolve this.

Comment: Hi I am facing the similar issue. If this issue is fixed please share the solution

Answer (score 1):

Without the actual error detail (please edit your question and add the detail of the error in there), it sounds to me like either a database corruption or a timeout issue.

Timeout errors on a database almost always point to lacking database maintenance, so first things I would look at is updating the database stats and rebuilding the indexes. Always make sure you do regular database maintenance or its performance will deteriorate over time.

If you think it might be a database corruption, then it is very important that you contact SDL Customer Support and ask for their assistance in resolving the issue. Database corruption is not somthing which should happen, and certainly not something that can be solved via an answer here.

Comment: Hi Bart,, thanks a lot for responding. Actually if it were a db maintenance related issue, then it should be replicated over all the browsers across all systems. Though it is occurring on one machine only. Also I am not getting any error not in the logs not in the console of the browser. Only when I try to add a component as a link item it is just hanging the browser.

Comment: Ah so that is what you meant with "using 5 systems", indeed when you encounter the issue on only one client/browser then it sounds like more a client/browser issue. Maybe network related, or simply a broken system.

Comment: What browser does this happen with?  Have you tried other browsers?  What is the exact Tridion version used, 2011 SP1, 2011 SP1 HR1 or HR2?  You could also try a Fiddler trace, that may show what requests are taking longer here.

Comment: Hi Bart/Elena,, Thanks a lot for your time. I have got the issue but still need your help to resolve it. On that specific machine when I try to link components to a linked field tridion always open an overlay looking for a folder which is not existing. As the folder is not found it hangs the browser. I dont know why always from one publication it is trying to find items in that publication, I tried clearing browser cache still the error is same, when i try replicating the problem in IE then I got the folder error and it also got hanged. Please help